# Iphone3gs. Latest version of ios

Tags: iphone

I recently bought an Iphone from another person, I asked him to download the Clash of Clans game for me since I don't have an apple ID yet. Now that the CoC game had a new update, it needs his apple ID to update it. But unfortunately I can't contact him. Is there another way for me to use my account? Please help me

Comment: If you didn't have an Apple ID, how did you even set the phone up as yours?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately when you download apps, you take responsibility over the app.

If you want to update the app, you can do so by creating your own apple ID and downloading CoC (be sure to delete the app first).

This method works, and you can now download other apps – **one major downside though, you lose progress on your Clash of Clans**